# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 3.0.0 problem with relative path

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 WebAPI project with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 3.0.0. It has a domain xx.xx.com and a dynamic subdomain /something rewritten to / in my reverse proxy.

I've configured the UI to use a relative path with:

> c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "MY API V1");

The problem is the methods are called in the root of the domain instead of with a relative path and I get error 404 for all "Try it out"s.

It calls xx.xx.com/method instead of xx.xx.com/something/method.

Is there a way to overcome this issue without changing the reverse proxy behavior?